# Why is it valid to transform a normal RDD with a 3 field tuple into a key value pair in a map method?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

According to an online exercise, below code converts a String RDD - where each line is being parsed into a tuple with 3 fields by `toTuple()` - into a tuple with 2 fields, or in other words into a PairRDD.

Why does this work? I thought that after the => there is only expressions allowed. But is `(toTuple(x)._1, toTuple(x)._4)` an expression? Or am I completely wrong with my thinking?

```
val RddAsKvPair = filteredRDD.map(x => (toTuple(x)._1, toTuple(x)._4))
```

Comment: `(x, y)` returns a `Tuple2(x, y)` so yes it is an expression

Comment: Why would it not be allowed? `map` on `RDD[A]` has the following signature `map[B](f: (A) => B): RDD[B]` where B in this case is a `Tuple2`. Constructing a Tuple is no different than constructing an instance of any other type you defined i.e. `map( x => MyCustomeType(x, x)` I am not sure what part you are confused about

Comment: Thanks both. I’m still fairly new to Scala and functional programming. So it still needs to sink in how flexible this language is. I was confused because intuitively this code seemed to not do any operation on the RDD elements to me.